# Sum of indicator function

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Basically, I've got the score function $S_n = n^{-1/2}\sum^n_{i=1} sgn(X_i)$, where sgn(X) is the sign of X and I need to shore the epxectation of $S_n$ is 0. I read online somewhere that converting the sng function to an indicator function and summing them results in a binomial distribution. For example,

$n^{-1/2}\big(2\sum (\mathbb{1}_{\{X_i>0\}}-1) \big) = n^{-1/2}\big(2\sum \mathbb{1}_{\{X_i>0\}}-n \big) = n^{-1/2}\big(2Bin(n,\frac{1}{2})-n \big) = \frac{Bin(n,\frac{1}{2}) - \frac{n}{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{n}{4}}} = 0$.

Is this true or are there any other ways I can go about this?

Answer (score 1):

That seems excessive.

Expectation is linear: $\mathbf{E}(X + Y) = \mathbf E X + \mathbf E Y$ [even when $X$ and $Y$ are dependent].

So you just need to check/confirm that $\mathbf E \operatorname{sign}(X_1) = 0$. I am assuming here that these are identically distributed.

Comment: Does it follow that the Var($S_n$) = 1? Since $E(X^2) - E(X)^2$ = 1, because $X^2$ will always be +1?

Comment: @Taffy The rule for variance is $\operatorname{Var}(aX + bY) = a^2 \operatorname{Var} X + b^2 \operatorname{Var} Y$. So yes (making sure the constants work out correctly).